# Fade out on load with Jquery. Then, fade in on hover, and out on unhover, with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

On my blog app, when the front page loads, I want the twitter share buttons (one for each blog post) to fade out (so the user knows they're there, but they don't distract from the layout for long). When the user hovers over a post, I want the share button to fade back in, and then fade out again when un-hovered.

Right now I'm using Jquery to fade out on page load, and that works fine:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.t-share').fadeOut(6800)
```

However, I can't get it to fade in/out on hover/unhover using CSS. This is strange because there are several other links that appear/disappear when a user hovers/unhovers over a post, which I implemented with css transitions. However, when I tried to make the `.t-share` div do the same thing, it doesn't work. The `display: none;` property on the button doesn't change, but it changes for the other elements that are supposed to fade in.

Also, when hovering over the div when the button is fading out (that takes 6 seconds), I can see the CSS transition taking place (it also adds a border), but it continues to fade.

Here's the CSS:

```
&:hover {
    .t-share {
        display:inline-block;
        position:absolute;
        right:8px;
        top:8px;
        border:2px solid red;
    }
```

Did the JS disable CSS transitions somehow?

How can I get the button to fade in/out on hover/unhover using CSS, after Jquery fades out the button on-load?

If not possible, what's the JS solution?

Comment: Representative HTML? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your css transitions do not work because the fadeOut funcion sets the `.t-share` to `display: none` when it has faded out completely (I'm not sure if it does). You might want to test for that.

In the meantime you could go for 100% JS. This does not use pure CSS though...

```
$('.t-share')
  .mouseenter(function(){ $(this).fadeIn(200); })
  .mouseleave(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(200); })
  .fadeOut(6800);
```

Comment: fadeOut does set the `.t-share` to `display:none` after the 6.8 seconds is over (it changes the opacity until then), but even after it's set, it won't fade back in. The JS example doesn't seem to work- it fades out ok, but won't fade back in on hover.

Comment: I think it won't fade back in because when its 'display' has been set to 'none' there is no element to move your mouse over. It cannot be moused over so to speak. You could try fading it 1% so it canot be hidden. Use fadeTo to do that.

Comment: My bad- forgot to mention that another element (`.post`) triggers the fade-in/out on the `.t-share` element within it. The JS above works. Still curious as to why the CSS solution doesn't work.

Comment: You could try to remove the display:none from the dom element using firebug or something similar and then hover over the .post. If that does work then you know that it had something to do with the display property and you can search further from there. It if still does not work then it something else. And I have no idea what that something would be. :/ Happy to hear that the scripts I provided worked.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. For now I'll stick with the JS solution. This is the modified coffeescript solution I used: `jQuery ->
  $('.t-share').fadeOut(6800)
  $(".post").mouseenter(->
    $(this).find('.t-share').fadeIn 0
  ).mouseleave(->
    $(this).find('.t-share').fadeOut 0
  )`